# How to block certain websites in Tor

Tags: censorship

I'm using getcoldturkey.com to block social networks from myself so that I don't overuse them. But I still can access them with Tor which is kinda cool. But anyway is there a way I can block websites in Tor?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've solved the problem myself. I can block applications with the same software as well. So, I blocked Tor browser.