# How do i block websites in the tor browser, productivity filter

Tags: network-configuration, censorship, add-on

I need to block a bunch of different websites, otherwise my productivity goes to crap.

There have been a couple of questions asked here, but no one has given a good answer that I can see.

[How to block certain websites in Tor](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1964/how-to-block-certain-websites-in-tor)

[How block clearnet in Tor browser?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/11729/how-block-clearnet-in-tor-browser)

[blocking websites without breaking annonmytity.](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/14900/blocking-websites-without-breaking-annonmytity)

[Block TOR websites on browser manually](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/21293/block-tor-websites-on-browser-manually)

There has to be a way of making it so that some websites are inaccessible. Are there any good / trusted addons I can use? Ublock is to easy to quickly disable.

To highlight how far I need to go to prevent my lazy butt from spending all day on youtube, before I started using tor I had my firewall rules protected by a random 50 digit password written on a piece of paper

Please help. My safety would be at risk If I did not use tor,  but over the last month I have gotten very little done, and its because I have not been able to figure out how to do content blocking in a secure way. Its fine if it reduces my privacy a little, but I dont want to install some random ad-on.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the domain names of the websites you want to block, you can do this easily if you edit your Tor configuration file (the `torrc` file). You can read how to do this here: https://support.torproject.org/tbb/tbb-editing-torrc/

To block these websites, you want to use Tor's `MapAddress` option. This redirects requests for one address to another, so in this case we can map the domain name we want to block to the local computer's address, which will cause the browser to give an "Unable to connect" error. For example, to block google.com, add the following line to your `torrc` file:

```
MapAddress *.google.com 127.0.0.1
```

You can add this line as many times as you like for as many domain names as you'd like. The `*` is a wildcard to match google.com and subdomains such as drive.google.com.

**Note:** This may harm your privacy if other websites are able to tell that third-party requests to these domain names fail. I make no claims about any privacy implications of blocking websites in Tor Browser.